# Why Would I Not Be Able To Offer +50 Bounties?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I recently offered my first bounty and only was able to choose values of +100, +200, or +300.Now it looks like I have 50 point increments up to +500. Is there something special about your first bounty or is it on a per question basis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks pretty well explained in the [bounty help page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

In general:

> A bounty is a special reputation award given to answers. It is funded
>   by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is
>   non-refundable. If you see a question that has not gotten a
>   satisfactory answer, a bounty may help attract more attention and more
>   answers. Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned
>   reputation, and attach it to any question as a bounty. You do not need
>   to be the asker of the question to offer a bounty on it.

Additionally:

> - To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum
>     spend is 100 reputation (not 50).
> - Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation
>     on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third,
>     and so on).

Comment: Yep, I had already answered it. Thanks for the help.